# How to hide Code in Jupyter Notebook w/ VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm using VS Code to write Jupyter notebook as I feel more comfortable with it. I found out that there is no option to edit meta data of the cells in order to hide only select code cells. I also came across some answers suggesting to use # @hidden_cell in the code cell but that doesn't work or am I doing it wrong? not much information was available for this.
I tried using the command

```
jupyter nbconvert my_notebook.ipynb --no-input --to pdf
```

and that works fine but it removes all the code. I wish to remove only specific code cells.

Comment: According to my knowledge, `VS Code` have a shortcut of this i.e. `Ctrl + K` and then `Ctrl + C` to hide selected cells.

Comment: @FareedKhan Collapsing code cells doesn't make them hide in the export PDF/HTML.

Comment: In addition to what @FareedKhan mentioned, you can also hide a code cell in VS code by clicking the vertical bar left of the code cell. Unfortunately, in both cases you still can read the first line of the code cell.

Answer (score 2):

You can use .env to hide the code.

```
hidden_code = (code)
```

Then use the variable hidden_code inside brackets to use it.

Comment: I believe if you can provide an example, it will be better for the community

Comment: Can you please provide an example? Thank you.